# How do I add a scoreboard listing the health of other players when I press TAB?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I really need to know how to set a command where the health of a player can be seen when you press TAB in-game. It must show the players amount of hearts as displayed on the top of their hotbar in-game. I hope you get the point of what I'm trying to say and I hope you can help me!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @happyMelonday_ There appears to be a good answer that reasonably answers your question. Ignoring Frank, it's considered good etiquette to accept an answer that works.

Answer (score 15):

Create an objective for players' health values:

```
/scoreboard objectives add health health
```

Set the objective to display in the <kbd>TAB</kbd> list:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay list health
```